# "GenerateAppxPackageRecipe" task was not given a value for the required parameter "AppxManifestXml"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Just updated to [VS2015 Update 3 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) and now can't build UWP solution in Release configuration because of the following error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2194,5): **error MSB4044: The "GenerateAppxPackageRecipe" task was not given a value for the required parameter "AppxManifestXml"**.

It was fine a few minutes ago with VS2015 **Update 2** and no any code changes since then.

Anyone experience something like this after update (or with fresh VS2015 Update 3 RC installation)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, repairing *VS2015 Update 3 RC* fixed the build issue.