# Cordova build UWP error : The "GenerateAppxPackageRecipe" task was not given a value for the required parameter "AppxManifestXml"

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to build a release appx package for Windows 10 UWP with Cordova CLI. But the build fails with the following error :

**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2168,5): error MS
B4044: The "GenerateAppxPackageRecipe" task was not given a value for the required parameter "AppxManifestXml".**

How can I fix it ?

Additional information : I'm using Visual studio 2015 Enterprise.

Thanks.

Comment: [repair VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37956244)

Comment: Repairing VS 2015 didn't work. I have downloaded VS Community 2017 to solve the problem.

Comment: Having this same problem on Adobe Phonegap Build